# Can't solve this error Program.cs(14,33): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'char[]'

Tags: c#

I'm doing a course struggling to find out mistake I've made.

Question
Create a new, empty array of characters to hold the encrypted message. It should be named encryptedMessage and have a length equal to the length of secretMessage.

Code:

```
  Console.WriteLine("Please enter message: ");
  string message = Console.ReadLine();
  char[] secretMessage = message.ToCharArray();
  char[] encryptedMessage = secretMessage.Length;
```

error
Program.cs(14,33): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'char[]' [/home/ccuser/workspace/csharp-caesar-cipher/CaesarCipher.csproj]

Comment: property `Length` has type `int`, not `char[]`.

Comment: How do I convert

Comment: With the line number being provided, what have you tried to troubleshoot the error?

Comment: `Length` is an `int`, and you're trying to assign it to a `char []`, which is causing the error. The error message tells you the specific line and position of the problem, and exactly what the problem is, so you should be able to spot it yourself if you actually read the words in the error message.

Comment: @Edward please reread your task)) You don't need to convert length of `secretMessage` to `encryptedMessage `

Comment: Ah. My old nemesis reading things properly.

Comment: @Edward you are assigning `encryptedMessage ` instead your task is to initialize an array at the same lenght of you secret message. You need to read again your task ;)

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned already, the type returned by `secretMessage.Length` is `int`, so if you just declare `encryptedMessage` as `int` instead of `char[]`, it should work.

```
  Console.WriteLine("Please enter message: ");
  string message = Console.ReadLine();
  char[] secretMessage = message.ToCharArray();
  int encryptedMessage = secretMessage.Length;
```

This will get rid of the error. But this will not solve the question stated in the OP.

Now to create an empty char array with size of `secretMessage` you can do -

```
  Console.WriteLine("Please enter message: ");
  string message = Console.ReadLine();
  char[] secretMessage = message.ToCharArray();
  char[] encryptedMessage = new char[secretMessage.Length];
```